# Laravel Eloquent firstOrNew not populating attributes on "new" condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I officially tap on this -- I can't wrap my head around what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to use `::firstOrNew` to check for the existence of a record or to create the object instance for it. The issue is that when I pass values to it that I *know* are not in the database, the subsequent model that is created has absolutely no properties set on it. the code looks a bit like this (trimmed down some random bloat)

```
if($old_value != ''){
    list($old_tag, $oldV) = explode(':', $old_value);
    list($new_tag, $value) = explode(':', $new_value);
    //Get the new tag / old tag, new value / old value

    $tag = CdwTagging::firstOrNew(['tagging'=>$old_tag], [ 'value'=>$old_value, 'segment'=>$tag_section]);

    if(!$tag->exists) {
       //do some logical stuff based on other values, etc.
       $tag->save();
    }
}
```

My code is based on [This Link from the Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent).

If I add in a `dd($tag)` into this my output is:

I have checked to see if the arrays I am using actually hold values (as in: perhaps I had messed up in gathering the data) and I can assure you that the values are exactly what is sent through the form.

```
CdwTagging {#320
  #table: "cdw_tagging"
  #fillable: array:3 [
    0 => "segment"
    1 => "tagging"
    2 => "value"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

and if I ignore that and say 'well maybe because it's new it doesn't show the properties yet' and call the `->save()` method anyway I get an error such as

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'segment' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `cdw_tagging` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2017-12-01 22:59:11, 2017-12-01 22:59:11))

I feel like I must be doing something wrong in how I am trying to use this method, but I have to be tired or something because I can't figure out *what*. Thanks for any help or ideas you may have

Comment: Also: in case someone finds the same thing, I did double check the `$fillable` attribute on the CdwTagging model, it is set to `['segment','taggin','value']`

Comment: what is the value of `$tag_section`

Comment: it's a string value -- I can assure you it is there.

Comment: The value is really irrelevant because even if i straight set the value on the object, like `$tag->segment = "orange"` then the error simply changes to one of the other fields because they don't have default values either.

Comment: did you for some odd reason override the constructor on the model?

Comment: default constructor `function __construct(){}`

Comment: It's the constructor that's created on literally every Eloquent model I've ever made, minus a commented line. Seems pretty default.

Comment: okay, great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: np, you are a better man than I am :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor for models is as follows:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
```

It takes **attributes**. New instances can have attributes filled when they are created, which is what happens with `firstOrNew`.

If you decide for some odd reason to not take those attributes in your constructor, then your attributes wont be assigned to the model instance when it is being created via `new Model($attributes)`.

Answer (score 1):

It might be silly, but I had the same issue, and the problem was both of `fillable` and `guarded` were improperly configured. So I had this:

```php
public $fillable = ['*'];
```

instead of:

```php
protected $guarded = ['id'];
```

And that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because it does not send a value for the column segment when you do insert.

If just for testing, you allow NULL or set a default value for column segment in table cdw_tagging, does it work?

Comment: The error is indeed because the field column named "segment" doesn't have a default value, however the values passed from `firstOrCreate` _should_ add the segment. The direct output of the `CdwTagging::firstOrCreate()` is ouput in my question -- none of the fields are populated, which is the issue I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have put 'segment' in 2nd parameter (i.e. **Optional**). You should do something like this:

```
['tagging'=>$old_tag, 'segment'=>$tag_section], [ 'value'=>$old_value]
```

One more thing... the variable **$tag_section** is what I can't see in your code. Maybe it is assigning `NULL` value in segment.

ref:https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#other-creation-methods